# If i get visa of different countries around duration but Im doing training in USA n then i receive australia visa 407 of australia and time overlaps?

Tags: visas, usa, australia, countries

If I get visa of different countries around duration but Im doing training in USA n then i receive australia visa 407 of australia and time overlaps

I have 9 months left to complete my USA J1 exchange visa training in hotel work. Can I terminate the US training in order to take up a 407 training visa in Australia, which I applied for 18 months back? The Australian visa requires me to arrive within 6 months’ of issue, meaning it would overlap with my US stay.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Your question is unclear.  Do you already have a US visa? What training are you doing in the US and when does that end? Are you asking if you can terminate the US training early to take up a programme in Australia? Have you already been sponsored and/or applied for an [Australian Training visa 407](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/training-407)? What would be the start date?

Comment: Yes i already have USA visa J1 exchange visa training in hotel I'm doing and yes I'm asking can i terminate the US training and go to Australia which i applied 18 months back was doubt full about it all of sudden I m also about to get 407 training visa for Australia I can fly with in 6 months but i still left with USA training 9 months left to complete USA one I m in situation what should I do now ?

Comment: ​​If you plan to withdraw from your program, you must notify your program sponsor.  Your program sponsor will enter this information into SEVIS and you will be expected to depart the United States immediately.  You will not be entitled to the post-completion 30-day period because you did not successfully complete your program https://www.j1training.org/faq.html

Answer (score 6):

As I understand it you are currently doing training in the US on a J1 visa, and still have more than six months before you finish that training. You have received an Australian 407 visa for a different kind of training, which has to start within 6 months.

If you stop doing your training in the US then that will have some effects on you. Obviously you will not receive the qualification that you hoped to get from the US. You may be able to ask your US school if you can pause your training and finish it later. You have to ask the school, and it will be entirely up to them. If you just stop without arranging continuation then you probably forfeit any tuition payments you have made.

In any case when you stop the training in the US (whether or not you intend to continue it) you must tell your school who will tell US immigration. Your J1 will stop being valid, and you need to leave the US immediately. You will have to apply for another J1 if you want to continue your studies in the US. If you don't tell your school that would be immigration fraud and would seriously damage your chances of ever getting back into the US.

The alternative approach would be to contact whatever school you wish to study at in Australia and ask if you can delay the start of your studies there until after your US training has finished. You would then need to apply for another Australian visa. If you have been granted one already it is likely that you would be granted another for the same course.

Comment: Tq for the it's really helpful @DJclayworth